# Python - Generating Set of Correlated Data Based on Existing Set of Data

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, statistics

So I have a set of data and I want to generate another set that of data of the same size with a set mean that is normally distributed that is correlated to the data I already have.

I looked up stats.multivariate_normal and cholesky decomposition but that generates two (or more) sets of data.  Is there anyway to generate only one set of data based on something already existing in Python?

```
# 100 random samples
x = stats.norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=100)

# What we got
n = 100
std_x = x.std()
mean_x = 0
mean_y = 1

# What I need
std_y = ?

# Means of x and what we want for y
mean_xy = [0, 1]

#Desired correlation matrix
r= [[1,0.83], [0.83,1]]

# How do I generate 100 random samples of y with a normal distribution with a mean 1 that has a 0.83 correlation with x?
```

Thank you for any help!!!!

Answer (score 2):

See the section in the Wikipedia article about the multivariate normal distribution which is about [the bivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_conditional_expectation). You have sigma_1 = 1, sigma_2 = 1, rho = 0.83, mu_1 = 1, mu_2 = 0 in their notation (note that in their notation, x_1 = y and x_2 = x in your notation).

So E(x_1 | x_2) = mu_1 + rho times sigma_1/sigma_2 times (x_2 - mu_2) = 1 + 0.83 times x_2 after substituting values. Also the conditional variance var(x_1 | x_2) = 1 - rho^2 = 1 - 0.83^2 (i.e. same for all x_2). (Conditional variance is stated for mu_1 = mu_2 = 0, but it's the same no matter what mu_1 and mu_2 are.)

So for your problem, take x as a given, then compute mean_y = 1 + 0.83 times x, and std_y = sqrt(var(y|x)) = sqrt(1 - 0.83^2), and generate y = mean_y + std_y times N(0, 1), where N(0, 1) = sample from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.